# How can I test that no attribute on a model has been modified using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to check if no attributes on an ActiveRecord object have been modified. Currently I'm doing this:

`prev_attr = obj.attributes` <- this will give me back a Hash with attr name and attr value

And then, later, I grab the attributes again and compare the 2 hashes. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use [equality matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/equality-matchers) - does this not work for you?

```
a = { :test => "a" }
b = { :test => "b" }
$ a == b
=> false
b = { :test => "a" }
$ a == b
=> true
```

Or to use your example:

```
original_attributes = obj.attributes
# do something that should *not* manipulate obj
new_attributes = obj.attributes
new_attributes.should eql original_attributes
```

Answer (score 11):

There is another way indeed. You can do it like this :

```
it "should not change sth" do
  expect {
    # some action
  }.to_not change{subject.attribute}
end
```

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change.

Comment: But, what if I have multiple attributes?

Comment: I guess `change{%w{name title description}.map { |attr| subject.send(attr) }}` will work fine as it will generate an array of the attributes' value which RSpec should be able to compare correctly.

Comment: Bit concerned about the maintainability of this - what if I add a new attribute to the model? ... And another? I would need to keep returning to this test to update it.

Comment: You can test the subject, not just the attribute(s) `expect{foo}.not_to change{my_object}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html). It gives you a `changed?` method on your model which is truthy if any attribute of the model was actually changed and falsey if not. You also have `_changed?` methods for each attribute, e.g. `model.subject_changed?` which is truthy if that attribute was changed compared to when the object was read from the database.

To compare attribute values, you can use `model.subject_was` which will be the original value the attribute had when the object was instantiated. Or you can use `model.changes` which will return a hash with the attribute name as the key and a 2-element array containing the original value and the changed value for each changed attribute.

Comment: Keep in mind that once the changes are saved, `changed?` will return `false`. So the test could pass under scenarios where in fact it has been changed.

Comment: Of course, but unless you test deeply nested code, it's often a good idea to not save the model at all, if only to conserve performance of the test suite. Given that, using AR::Dirty is still the easiest way to check an in-flight model instance, even more so outside of rspec (and I thus don't think this answer deserves a downvote).

Comment: It's not about testing deeply nested code of should/should not save models. It's about the test providing a consistent, repeatable result. Using `AR::Dirty` has clear scenarios where the internals of the code under test could cause it to return a false positive. Therefore, I think it shouldn't be used.

Comment: I'm all for "easiest way", hence my answer simply using equality matchers (which would be consistent).

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but as is mentioned here, I prefer it due to maintainability.

The attributes are cached, and since they're not changed directly you'll have to reload them if you want to check them all at once:

```
it 'does not change the subject attributes' do
  expect {
    # Action
  }.to_not change { subject.reload.attributes }
end
```

Avoid reloading if you can, since you're forcing another request to the database.